# How do I add an item to an array in a database using a PATCH request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a model in a mongoDB database, and one of the fields keeps track of which "reviews" a user has "liked" by storing the unique review ID number. I set up the field as an array in the DB. I can add a single review ID to the array using the code below, but additional IDs just replace the first one. Is there something in the code below that I can add to indicate that I want to add or "push" a new item into the array?

Client side JS file:

```
export const likeButtonUser = async (userId, userLikes) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'PATCH',
      url: `/api/v1/users/${userId}`,
      data: {
        userLikes,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

API Code:

route:

```
router.route('/:id').patch(userController.updateUser);
```

userController:

```
exports.updateUser = factory.updateOne(User);
```

Factory updateOne:

```
exports.updateOne = (Model) =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const doc = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      new: true,
      runValidators: false,
    });

    if (!doc) {
      return next(new AppError('No document found with that ID!', 404));
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'Success',
      data: {
        data: doc,
      },
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the part that's wrong:

```
const doc = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
  new: true,
  runValidators: false,
});
```

You want to add a MongoDB operator called [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

It will look something like this:

```
const doc = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {"$addToSet": {userLikes: req.body}}, {
  new: true,
  runValidators: false,
});
```

But in this case `userLikes` will be whatever you named the array field in the model.

If this doesn't work, please let me know!

Comment: Thank you!!!! I’m going to try this. Out of curiosity, is there a MongoDB operator that you know of that will do the reverse, and remove an item from a set?

Comment: Glad to help! And yes, you want `$pull`. I think it removes all values that match.